# Changed this CSS Class but it doesn't working

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want to change background-color Class .theme--light.v-tabs > .v-tabs-bar vuetify in nuxtJS but it doesn't working.

```
enter code here
<!-- template -->
<div class="tabCourse">
 <v-tabs
  v-model="tabMenu"
  class="tabMenu"
 >
  <v-tab
   v-for="menu in courseMenu"
   :key="menu.key"
   :ref="menu.key"
   class="tabMenuName"
  >
   <h4>{{ menu.text }}</h4>
  </v-tab>
 </v-tabs>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
<style scoped>
 .tabCourse .tabMenu .theme--light.v-tabs > .v-tabs-bar{
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: try removing scoped

Comment: It's working now. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to use scoped css, sometimes you might need modify your css and include the deep selectors. https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is `scoped`: You have to remove `scoped` or use deep selectors.

```html
<style>
 .tabCourse .tabMenu .theme--light.v-tabs > .v-tabs-bar{
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
</style>
```

or

```html
<style scoped>
 .tabCourse::v-deep .tabMenu .theme--light.v-tabs > .v-tabs-bar{
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }
</style>
```

See more: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html